# promise.all() instead of nesting functions in express application

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

Basically, I have 2 function which copy blob from src to destination folders, hence I am trying to use promise.all in my node.js application. but I am getting ReferenceError: promise is not defined error.can anyone look at the following code and tell where I have done the mistake? should I include try/catch inside return new promise(resolve,reject){}?

```
export.addrestartjob=async function(req,res){
some var....
//return new promise(resolve,reject){
try {
const msg = await xxx();
const msg1 = await aaa();
let resp = await promise.all([msg, msg1]);
return res.status(200).json({
status: 'success',data:resp
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}

// }
}
const xxx = async function () {
return new Promise(resolve => {
setTimeout(() => { resolve('yes'); }, 300);
});
}
const aaa = async function () {
return new Promise(resolve => {
setTimeout(() => { resolve('yesssssssssssssss'); }, 100);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `promise.all()`

```
 exports.addRestartJob =function (req, res) {
    // some variables...
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var containerName = name;
    
     let tasks = [];
     tasks.push(blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, blobName));

     tasks.push(blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri1, containerName, blobName1));

     tasks.push(blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri2, containerName, blobName2));

    promise.all(tasks)
    .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
    })
    });
    }
```

Comment: blobService.startCopyBlob(), there are 3 different tasks , I am trying to write seperate fn expressions and call them inside addrestartjob() is that possible?if yes,how can i do that? do i have to use asynch/await/?

Comment: if answer is useful, then please make it useful.

Comment: blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, blobName),blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri1, containerName, blobName1));
blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri2, containerName, blobName2));   these are 3 different services so i want to write them in seperate function and return promise event and then i would like to use them in export.addrestartjob().

Answer (score 0):

```
    > Using `async/await function`
    
        exports.addRestartJob =function async (req, res) {
        // some variables...
        
        var containerName = name;
    
try{
         let result1 = await blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri, containerName, 
                             blobName)
         if (!!result1)
          // if success copy someother blob
    
         let result2 = await blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri1, containerName, 
                             blobName1)
         if (!!result2)
          // if success copy someother blob
    
         let result3 = await blobService.startCopyBlob(storageuri2, containerName, 
                             blobName2)
         if (!!result3)
          // if success copy someother blob
    
   return() // return something from function
}catch(err){
  // if any one function get error
  console.log(err);
}
}
```